# Converting fasta file into list with names and sequences

Tags: python, list, dictionary, fasta

Goal: Return a list of the names and sequences

```
def ReadFastaFile(filename):
  fileObj = open(filename, 'r')
  sequences = []
  seqFragments = []
  for line in fileObj:
    if line.startswith('>'):
      if seqFragments:
        sequence = ''.join(seqFragments)
        sequences.append(sequence)
      seqFragments = []
    else:
      seq = line.rstrip()
      seqFragments.append(seq)
  if seqFragments:
    sequence = ''.join(seqFragments)
    sequences.append(sequence)
  fileObj.close()
  return sequences
```

I want to get list with name and sequence
This code gives me a list with only the sequence, because i first thought i would not need the name for what I want to do. But now i realized that it would be good to also include the names. Maybe if possible also in a dictionary form, so that it is like: `dict = {'name':sequence}`. Does somebody have I idea how to alter the code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty straightforward:

```
def ReadFastaFile(filename):
  fileObj = open(filename, 'r')
  sequences = dict()
  seqFragments = []
  for line in fileObj:
    if line.startswith('>'):
      if seqFragments:
        sequence = ''.join(seqFragments)
        sequences[id] = sequence
      seqFragments = []
      id = line.rstrip()[1:]
    else:
      seq = line.rstrip()
      seqFragments.append(seq)
  if seqFragments:
    sequence = ''.join(seqFragments)
    sequences[id] = sequence
  fileObj.close()
  return sequences
```